# facebook sdk 4.1 for android: how to handle token expiration

Tags: android, facebook

I made an app for android, which uses facebook login. Sometimes after the app update through the play store I start the app and I'm not logged in anymore (access token is `null`). How to handle this situation? Should I forward the user to the login page, so that the user can manually log in or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [at this article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) from Facebook docs:

> If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and
>   the person **will have to go through the login flow again** to get a new
>   token.